# Allow duplicate lines in XY to Lines using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, xy

I am a complete beginner with ArcGIS Pro.

I have a table of people, each with year, workplace and birthplace coordinates. I'd like to visualize a connection between birth and workplace with time slider.

XY to Line tool works, but when using the time slider I noticed some stray unconnected points. After I found out that the problem is, that when more people share the same birthplace/workplace, there is only 1 line created for the first person.

Can you help me solve it?

Comment: For every row in your record you have start x and start y and end x and end y?  Does you data have an ID field and each row has a unique ID?